# How can I find out the user's IP address in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I would like to get the user's IP locally without any invoking any service.

Looking for a purely client side solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general this problem is not solvable because the client computer might not even *know* its own external IP address. This happens when the client is behind a NAT or some other kind of firewall.

Note that many different client machines might share the same external IP address, and also different client machines might have the *same* internal IP address but different external IP addresses. Or, I can even imagine a situation where two different clients have the same internal *and* external IP addresses.

If you would explain *why* you believe you need this information, another solution to your actual problem might be possible.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. I have resorted to getting the IP  via a server call.